# "Flush"/discard accumulating write() and read() calls in ros2_control hardware component/interface

Tags: ros, ros2, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to implement a triggered / on-demand / on-request communication with hardware using `ros2_control` framework.

In relation to a [previous question](https://answers.ros.org/question/399818) and [this answer](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/551#issuecomment-947174795) on a similar problem, i wrote a controller following [`forward_command_controller`](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/tree/galactic/forward_command_controller) implementation for ros2 galactic, which uses a `"settings"` command interface type and calls `LoanedCommandInterface.set_value(msg->data)` whenever a new message `msg` arrives on the controller's subscribed topic.

On the hardware component side, I exported the `"settings"` command interface and, inside the `write()` method I check if a new "setting" has been commanded like so:

```
if (!std::isnan(hw_command_settings_))
{
  int setting = hw_command_settings_;
  switch (setting)
  {
    case MY_FIRST_SETTING:
      /***********************
       *perform setting command
       ***********************/
      break;
  }
  hw_command_settings_ = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(); //reset setting request
  return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
}
//write() function continues with the other command interfaces...
```

If the implementation is real-time, there's no problem: the hardware component writes using the other standard interfaces (`"position"`, `"velocity"`...), and only if I send a message on the "`/settings_controller/command`" topic the setting command is performed.

However, the nature of these `"settings"` commands is not really real-time. I have a homing/calibrating command that needs to wait until the motor reaches a defined position before it's completed. So the `write()` function is blocked until this action is finished. However, when the normal control cycle is restored, i see a list of `write()` and `read()` calls that has been accumulating during this halting period (e.g. 5s halting with 10Hz control cycle results in 50 instant write() and read() calls after the halt). I believe this is like a default policy of `ros2_control_node`, but I'm very new to the framework and I don't really know.

Is there a way to avoid accumulating `read()` and `write()` calls when one of them is halted by a long procedure?
If not, is there a way to isolate the `"settings"` interface so that the `write()` method is kept real-time? Any other suggestion is really helpful.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399976/%22flush%22/discard-accumulating-write()-and-read()-calls-in-ros2_control-hardware-component/interface/) by [eldavio](https://answers.ros.org/users/103546/eldavio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have recently extended read/write with time parameters. This should allow you to implement some mechanism to skip writing certain interfaces by keeping accounts of the last time you accessed them.

https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/pull/715

Available in Humble and Rolling

---

Originally posted by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) with karma: 358 on 2022-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0